# IBM Mobile Migration : Worklight 6.2 to 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli

I am migrating IBM Worklight 6.2 application to IBM MobileFirst 8.0 using below guide

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/

I migrated the source code but when try to migrate adapters I am facing below issue.

```
**Version Details**
mvn -v 
Apache Maven 3.2.2

mfpmigrate -v
8.0.0-20180813050750

mfpdev -v
8.0.0-2018121711
```

> D:\Migration\26-11-2019\source\project>mfpmigrate server --In / --Out
>   D:/Migration/26-11-2019/destination/mproject
>
> Starting Migration for MFP 8 ...... Project root for migration is
>   D:\Migration\26-11-2019\source\project Scanning for security
>   realms.......
>
> **************** Starting  Migration of Realms ****************
>
> Realm Name    : SingleStepAuth Type          :
>   com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator
>
> Realm Name    : SampleApp Type          :
>   com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator
>
> Checking for Unsupported realms for MFP 8 .......
>
> wl_directUpdateRealm directupdate feature does not require realm
>   definition in 8.0
>   **************** Completed SecurityRealm Migration ****************
>
> (node:37428) DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global'
>   **************** Starting  Migration of Adapters ****************
>
> RootDir for AdapterMigration is
>   :D:\Migration\26-11-2019\source\project\adapters
>
> Name    : AboutUsAdapter Type    : javascript Protocol: http
>
> Error occured during Source Migration Error: Command failed: mvn -o
>   archetype:generate -B  -Dversion=1.0 -DarchetypeGrou pId=com.ibm.mfp 
>   -DarchetypeArtifactId=adapter-maven-archetype-http -DgroupId="com.sample" -DartifactId="UserDetailsAdap ter"
>
> **************** Completed Adapter Migration **************** Starting the process to detect deprecated and not supported APIs... Scanning
>   D:\Migration\26-11-2019\source\Project\OutDir/lib... Scanning
>   D:\Migration\26-11-2019\source\Project\OutDir/SampleApp... Scanning
>   D:\Migration\26-11-2019\source\Project\OutDir/SingleStepAuth... No
>   deprecated or not supported APIs found. Process to detect deprecated
>   and not supported APIs has completed.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am also having the same issue "Error occured during Source Migration"

Comment: @ZaheerBaloch have you done the migration of app/common source?

Comment: can you try   the following 
1. first run mfpdev adapter create  < and create a dummy http adapter>
2. after that run the tool mfpmigrate as above